# Mustache enumeration begin to n-element?

Tags: html, mustache

Is possible to define a mustache template to enumerate an array of elements but **begin at occurence n**?

Template:

```
{{#picts}}
    <img src="img/{{.}}"></img>
{{/picts}}
```

JSON:

```
{picts: [
    'p1.jpeg'
    , 'p2.jpeg'
    , 'p3.jpeg'
]}
```

I expect to obtain:

```
<img src="img/p2.jpeg"></img>
<img src="img/p3.jpeg"></img>
```

It would be something like:

```
{{#picts >1}}
    <img src="img/{{.}}"></img>
{{/picts}}
```

Comment: Use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). MustacheJS is logicless, what you are asking for cannot be done within the view.

Comment: Array. Slice is js isn't it?

Comment: Understood, it cannot be done

Comment: Correct, it may be possible with Handlebars - I don't use it. Certainly possible with Angular.

Comment: In this Java implementation of mustache there is a `{{^-first}}{{/-first}}` that can be used exactly for this https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache#-first-and--last

Comment: Cool, but i'm using javascript. Thanks for the valuable info